# User name not a link in comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-accounts, comments, hyperlinks

This question was migrated from stackoverflow: [XNA: Texture2D.GetData runtime error](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16415/xna-texture2d-getdata-runtime-error)

Bjørn Moholt's name on his comment doesn't have a link.

Answer (score 2):

This is *currently* [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83249/taking-ownership-of-comments-on-migrated-questions) - if the user doesn't have an account on the site when the comment is migrated, it'll be disassociated permanently.

Fortunately, this is not the case for questions and answers.